# how to auto close dialog box after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

How to close a dialog box after 5 sec?

```
function mydialog(){
  const options={
    type:'question',
    buttons:['Yes','No'],
    defaultId:[1,2],
    title:'Question',
    message:'Are You Attentive in the session?',
    detail:'Then only you will get attendence',
    checkboxLabel: 'Remember my answer',
    checkboxChecked:true,
  };
  dialog.showMessageBox(null, options, msg=>{console.log(msg); })
  console.log("dialog")
}

function loop() {
    console.log("executed")
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) * 600;
    var c = 200
    setTimeout(function() {
        c = c + 1
        mydialog();
        
    }, rand);
    console.log({rand})
}
setInterval(loop, 60000);
```

Comment: use `setTimeout`

Comment: What is not working above?

Comment: it is working fine, but I want the dialog box to close automatically after 5 sec if there is no response from the user

Comment: Declare an empty variable or a boolean and the timeout at the same time. If the user answers the question, store the answer in the empty variable or change the boolean and use that to trigger clearTimeout(). If no answer is provided, setTimeout will run till the time ends and will close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

look at this code.

[other author's answer](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5577)

```
// Make a new message box and close after n milliseconds
function tempBox(options, n){
     return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          const slave = new BrowserWindow({width: 1, height: 1, show: false});
          var resolved = false;
          const btn = dialog.showMessageBox(slave, options).then((index) => {
               resolved = true;
               resolve(index);
          }).catch(() => {});
          await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, n));
          slave.close();
          if (!resolved) reject();
     });
}
```