# I want the dialog box in electron to close automatically after 5 sec if there is no response from the user

Tags: javascript, electron

How to close a dialog box automatically after certain time. If, user is not responding to the dialog box?

```
function mydialog(){
  const options={
    type:'question',
    buttons:['Yes','No'],
    defaultId:[1,2],
    title:'Question',
    message:'Are You Attentive in the session?',
    detail:'Then only you will get attendence',
    checkboxLabel: 'Remember my answer',
    checkboxChecked:true,
  };
  dialog.showMessageBox(null, options, msg=>{console.log(msg); })
  console.log("dialog")
}

function loop() {
    console.log("executed")
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) * 600;
    var c = 200
    setTimeout(function() {
        c = c + 1
        mydialog();
        
    }, rand);
    console.log({rand})
}
setInterval(loop, 60000);
```

'''

Comment: Are you using [multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734010/how-to-auto-close-dialog-box-after-5-seconds)?

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5577) - not currently supported, but can use workaround in the answer